# View over Canvas Visibility issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.components.game.GameView
    android:id="@+id/game_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ChatLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ChatCancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ChatOkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="OK" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ChatEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ChatOkButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ChatCancelButton"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's a RelativeLayout over a canvas. At start time it's invisible but when a user clicks a button the layout should become visible.
The problem is that it's not becoming visible. The layout is there but it's just not drawing it. If I press the position where the layout should appear it receives the event and opens the keyboard but it's not drawing the whole layout.
What is the problem?

If I set the RelativeLayout to visible at the beginning it works fine. it shows the layout and if I toggle between invisible and visible it works fine.

I made a workaround that almost always works.
I start the layout visible and than do that in the oncreate:

```
chatLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            chatLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    }, 50);
```

But I don't like it and want to understand what's the problem.

The code:

It starts from a canvas button which send a message to a handler:

```
public void showInputLayout() {
    Message.obtain(gameHandler, SHOW_INPUT_LAYOUT).sendToTarget();
}
```

In the handler:

```
case SHOW_INPUT_LAYOUT:
                    gameActivity.setChatVisibility(true);
                    break;
```

setChatVisibility:

```
public void setChatVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
    int visible = isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
    chatLayout.setVisibility(visible);
    if(isVisible){
        chatEditText.setFocusable(true);
        chatEditText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the code of how you are making the view visible,after the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to `RelativeLayout` and switch the visibility between `GONE` and `VISIBLE`. Try something like this:

```
int visibility = View.VISIBLE;
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ChatLayout);
layout.setVisibility(visibility);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
            visibility = View.GONE;
        else
            visibility = View.VISIBLE;

        v.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I am setting the visibity it's just not drawing it, but it still receives events like it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently, and for my case the problem was actually in the onDraw() method of the view underneath (should be `com.components.game.GameView` in your case). See if you can add calls to Canvas' `getSaveCount()`, `save()` and `restoreToCount()` in your drawing code, similar to this:

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int saveCount = canvas.getSaveCount();
    canvas.save();

    // custom drawing code here ...
    // use Region.Op.INTERSECT for adding clipping regions

    canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
}
```

I believe what happened was that sometimes the framework set the clipping regions for the elements on top of our Canvas-drawing widget before our onDraw() method is called so we need to make sure that those regions are preserved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I'm already doing what you proposed so I guess it's not my case. What I don't know is what is Region.Op.INTERSECT? I didn't find anything on this subject.

Comment: You're welcome. The issue sounds very similar to mine so I thought it has the same culprit :) The `Region.Op` constants can be passed as an optional argument to the `clipPath()`, `clipRect()` and `clipRegion()` methods of [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). The default is `Region.Op.INTERSECT` though so if you haven't use anything else then it should not affect you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you comment out your GameView.onDraw() method completely? Does the chatLayout still does not become visible?

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.